# Understanding Domain Class in Project Job Scheduling

Tags: optaplanner

I am new to optaplanner, and right now I focus on trying to understand the project job scheduling. I trying to run this examples using the sample data from optaplanner manual like in this picture below:

[image]

I have some question about the domain classes in this example :

1. What is the difference of GlobalResource and LocalResource? In the examples, all the resource is GlobalResource right? Then what the use of LocalResource?
2. There are 3 JobType: SOURCE, STANDARD, SINK, what is the meaning each one of them? It is SOURCE mean the job should be the first to start before the others? STANDARD mean it is should be run after the predecessor job finished but not after the SINK job? SINK mean it is the last job to do after all job finished?
3. What is the meaning of property releaseDate and criticalPathDuration in Project class? If we related it with the picture above, what is the value for project Book1 and Book2?
4. What is the meaning of requirement in ResourceRequirement?

I will be really thankful if someone can help me create the xml sample data like in optaplanner distribution, cause it will help me more faster to understand this example. Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A LocalResource belongs to a specific Project, a GlobalResource is shared between the projects.
   So a LocalResource only has to be worry about being used by other jobs in the same Project too, while a GlobalResource has to worry about all other tasks.
2. That's an implementation trick. The source and sink jobs are dummy's basically. Because a project might start with multiple jobs in parallel, a SOURCE job is put in front of it, to have a single root. Same for the end: it can end with multiple, so a SINK job is put after it, to have a single tail. This makes it easier and faster to determine makespan etc.
3. IIRC, releaseDate is the first date we are allowed to start the first job. For example: you have to create a book, but you 'll only get the actual final content next Monday, so the releaseDate is next Monday (you can't start any work before that date).

The criticalPathDuration is a theoretical minimum duration (if we can happily ignore resources IIRC). For example: if job A takes 5 days and job B takes 2 days and B has to be done AFTER A, then the critical path duration is 7 days. Adding job C which takes 1 day and can be done in parallel with the others, don't affect that.

4. ResourceRequirement is the many2many relationship between ExecutionMode and Resource. Remember that ExecutionMode belongs to a specific Job. For example: doing job A in executionMode A1 requires 1 laborers and 5 days. Doing job A in executionMode A2 requires 2 laborers and 3 days.

Comment: 1. Could you explain more about this sharing resource things? Do you mean if project A has localResource R1, and has job J1 and J2 which are need resource R1, then both of the job can executed parallel?
2. So if I want to not allow any jobs executed parallel, I have to put a source job in front of each job?
Last things, if I want every resource to has a break for 1 day after working for 4 days, how should I do it? Please give me a suggestion. Thank you so much Geoffrey.

Comment: Just wonder, it is okay if we use the source and sink job? I mean, in the example, the duration was set to 0, can I set it to another value? Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't reuse the source and sink jobs with different durations than 0. Keep them as dummy's and just add an extra job.
Reason: the source and sink jobs are set to be immovable with NotSourceOrSinkAllocationFilter. That's a hack really - these days there is probably a nicer way to design this example - I 'll probably review it at some point (not soon though).

Comment: So based on the definition of criticalPathDuration,  to minimize the project duration, can I add a rule that minimizes the difference between criticalPathDuration and the actual duration of a project?